# Using a generic type in a collection, without using a generic class in C#

Tags: c#, generics, unity-game-engine

I have a situation where I have a class that is not generic, but it needs to store instances of objects that are generic in a collection. In the below example, I cannot make Foo generic, but I need to store Request objects in the pendingRequests dictionary. The following code will give an error on the declaration of pendingRequests that "using the generic type Request requires '1' type argument(s)" but if I add `<Response>` to the Request, then when I attempt to add to the dictionary in addRequest, I get a cast error.

I need to make the Dictionary declaration generic, but without making Foo generic. Can this be done, or should I be doing this another way? Too add a wrinkle to this, I'm stuck with .NET 2.0 because it needs to work with Unity 3d.

```
class Foo 
{
    private Dictionary<int, Request> pendingRequests;

    void addRequest<T>(int sequence, Request<T> request) where T : Response
    {
        pendingRequests[sequence] = request;
    }
}

class Request<T> where T : Response 
{
}

class Response
{
}
```

Comment: Can you create a non-generic `Request` class which takes the base as a parameter? `class Request : Request<Response>`?

Comment: You haven't explained why you can't use generics...

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Dictionary<int, Request<Response>>` and `addRequest(int seq, Request<Response> req)`?

Comment: @ErikPhilips I don't believe that I can make the the member pendingRequests generic without also making the class Foo generic.

Comment: @LeonardBrünings If I use Request<Response> then it won't let me pass in any objects that are children of Request ... such as LoginRequest<LoginResponse> ... to addRequest().

Comment: @user3208277 You encapsulate a generic (list, dictionary, etc) by settings it's parent type as generic as well.  You haven't explained why Foo can't be generic...

Comment: @ErikPhilips Foo cannot be generic because other than keeping a collection of generic Requests, it is complete Request independent. There is one instance of a Foo (call it a Session), but there are dozens of different types of Requests. It doesn't care that a request is a LoginRequest or a BuyMeRequest. However, the Request is generic because I'm using the supplied Response type to construct the correct type of Response object and deserialize it from the data that came in over the wire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the answer in a response to a different question. I can create a base class or interface for Request that isn't generic. The generic Request then inherits from the base non-generic Request. The non-generic Request is used for addRequest and the collection inside Foo. From my Java perspective, this is manually accomplishing the type-erasure that I'm used to.

```
class Foo 
{
    private Dictionary<int, IRequest> pendingRequests;

    void addRequest(int sequence, IRequest request)
    {
        pendingRequests[sequence] = request;
    }
}

class Request<T> : IRequest where T : Response 
{
}

class Response
{
}

interface IRequest
{
}
```

Comment: This is close, but doesn't provide 100% type safety (on get, you haven't provided a method, take a look at my answer for 100% type safety on get).  Make sure you null check your request (if using an interface or abstract base class).

Comment: @ErikPhilips It provides type safety in so much that whatever interface is defined in IRequest must be complete, which is exactly what I was looking for :) Basically, I wanted to be able to use the members defined in Request that didn't rely on the generic, but since I had made it generic (for other internal purposes) I was stuck dealing with it as a generic in Foo. My solution is to move the definition of those members to IRequest and then use that instead of the generic Request. Should be 100% safe - no casting required anywhere. Does that make sense?

Comment: Sure, if you're not casting, then why have `<T>`...  otherwise you'll have casting somewhere..

Answer (score 0):

> Foo cannot be generic because other than keeping a collection of generic Requests, it is complete Request independent. There is one instance of a Foo (call it a Session), but there are dozens of different types of Requests. It doesn't care that a request is a LoginRequest or a BuyMeRequest. However, the Request is generic because I'm using the supplied Response type to construct the current type of Response object and deserialize it from the data that came in over the wire.

Then your collection should not be *generic* either.  You might want to consider forgoing generic definitions and simply use inheritance.  This should get you on the way, although not 100%, your question is vague on usage.  Granted this uses LINQ (I think is 3.5+ or higher) it should be pretty easy to migrate it to 2.0.

```
public class Foo 
{
  // initialize: best practice
  private List<CacheRequest> _pendingRequests =
    new List<CacheRequest>();

  // upper case: best practice
  public void AddRequest(int sequence, Request request)
  {
    if (request.Response == null)
    {
      throw new ArgumentException("Request Response cannot be null.");
    }

    _pendingRequests.Add(new CacheRequest()
    {
      Sequence = sequence,
      Request = request,
      ResponseType = request.Response.GetType()
    });
  }

  public bool TryGetRequest<T>(int seq, out Request request, out T response)
    where T : Request
  {
    response = null;
    request = null;

    var pendingRequest = _pendingRequests
      .Where(cr => cr.ResponseType == typeof(T))
      .FirstOrDefault(r => r.Sequence  == seq);

    var result = pendingRequest != null;

    if (result)
    {
        request = pendingRequest.Request;
        response = request.Response as T;
    }

    return result;
  }

  private class CacheRequest
  {
    public int Sequence { get; set; }
    public Request Request { get; set; }
    public Type ResponseType { get; set; }
  }
}

public class Request
{
 public Response Response { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Response { }

public class HttpResponse : Response { }

public class UdpResponse : Response { }
```

Example:

```
    var foo = new Foo();
    
    foo.AddRequest(1, new Request() { Response = new HttpResponse() });
    
    Request request;
    HttpResponse httpResponse;
    UdpResponse udpResponse;
    
    
    if (foo.TryGetRequest<HttpResponse>(1, out request, out httpResponse))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("1 is an HttpResponse"); 
    }
    
    if (!foo.TryGetRequest<UdpResponse>(1, out request, out udpResponse))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("1 is not a UdpResponse"); 
    }
```

output:

> 1 is an HttpResponse
>
> 1 is not a UdpResponse

[DotNetFiddle Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yjoorJ)

Comment: Thanks! I think I see what you're going for there. I believe the base class/interface solution I found a few minutes ago gets the answer I was looking for more directly. Please review it and unless there's a problem with the answer, I'm planning on accepting that one even though I wrote it myself.

Comment: Absolutely mark your answer if it answers your question :)